# How to read each and every row of csv by single user in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

I have a CSV file which contains 10 server names. I want to read entire 10 rows by each and every thread of my thread group.

```
Thread 1 reads row1,row2....row 10  
Thread 2 reads row1,row2....row 10
```

But currently my test script read the file as below,

```
Thread 1 reads row1  
Thread 2 reads row2  
Thread 3 reads row3
```

Comment: [Got the answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Comment: Does my post answer your question?

Answer (score 3):

There are two options:

- [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) with Sharing Mode=Current Thread
- [Variables From CSV File](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/VariablesFromCSV)

Read docs and see which one will be better for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below function instead of variable:

```
${__FileToString(/path/to/your/file,,)}
```

You don't need to use the CSV reader as you want entire file content to be stored in a variable. The below image explains how the entire file content is passed as a parameter value to the HttpRequest.

[image]

Comment: Instead of what variable? How would it help? What does it do? Is there any reference? You could improve your answer by adding additional information to it.