# Use same row per thread from a CSV data set in JMeter

Tags: java, csv, jmeter, load-testing

I want to make a test plan in `JMeter` as follows:

I have a specific flow with a web server:

```
Req1  
Reply for Req1  
Req2  
Reply for Req2  
Req2  
Reply for Req2    
etc
```

I need to have these run as a **single** flow i.e. *each thread* executes this from start to finish (**not** `Req1` and `Req2` send by different threads).
I also need to send different parameters in each iteration so I used `CSV data set`.

**Problem:**
I need to send the same row from CSV for all the requests per thread.

**For example:**
If I have the following CSV:

```
john,A1111,engineer  
bill,A2111,manager  
mary,C1111,secretary
```

I need the first row to be send in **all** the flow from `Req1` to the last request by thread 1 and the second row by thread 2 in **all** requests etc.

Is this possible? I tried adding the same CSV file to all my controllers but still does not work as expected.

**Update:**
What I am interested in is having each thread consume 1 row from the CSV file and "cache" that row for **all** requests in my flow.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to read each and every row of csv by single user in JMeter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13060694/how-to-read-each-and-every-row-of-csv-by-single-user-in-jmeter)

Comment: @AndreyBotalov:I don't think it is the same question.Please see update for what I want to do

Comment: I've misunderstood your question

Comment: @AndreyBotalov:Do you have a suggestion on the best way to do this?I did something (put the CSV in a top controller and the requests as child controllers) and seems to work.But is it correct this way?

Comment: it seems to be a correct way

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to implement your scenario is like the following:

```
Test Group
Number of Threads = N
    CSV Data Set Config
    Filename: ... (your csv-file here)
    Variable Names: name,id,position       // (as per your csv sample above)
    Delimiter: ,
    Recycle on EOF = True
    Stop Thread on EOF = False
    Sharing Mode = All threads
    Simple Controller  // that's optional: simply to group your requests flow
        Sampler 01     // use ${name}, ${id}, ${position} variables to refer extracted values
        Sampler 02
        ...
        Sampler X
```

- `Number of Threads = N` will start N threads;
- `Sharing Mode = All threads` or `Sharing Mode = Current thread group` will enforce each thread to read separate row from csv and then use extracted values in all the subsequent samplers;
- `Recycle on EOF = True` will recycle your csv if number of threads N > number of entries in csv.